# Targeting a 64-bit OS in an InstallScript InstallShield project

Tags: windows, 64-bit, installshield, installscript

I am at my wit's end with this and our CM just, ahem... left the company.

I have a 32-bit InstallScript based InstallShield installer that I have copied and modified to install the 64-version of our software.  It properly grabs everything from the correct (x64) location and everything is good.

The only problem is figuring out what I need to change in order for the OS to recognize that this installer is installing 64-bit components and that they need to be placed into the Program Files folder (as opposed to Program Files (x86).

I have found plenty of information regarding how to do this when you have an MSI based project.  Unfortunately, all of the options that are referenced in the documentation do not exist in an InstallScript based project.

As setup.exe is a 32-bit executable I am assuming that it is querying the Program Files dir and getting back the 32-bit version.  I simply have no idea how to build it as an x64 exe or otherwise how to workaround this fact.

I can't find anything in the documentation that explains how to accomplish this task.  I am using InstallShield 2011, thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeesh, the answer was simple enough.  Changed

```
TARGETDIR = PROGRAMFILES ^ "Target\\Dir";
```

To:

```
TARGETDIR = PROGRAMFILES64 ^ "Target\\Dir";
```

Seems to work fine for uninstall as well.